# Replace dated light fixture mounted to metal stem in ceiling medallion

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I recently took down an old chandelier that I found was screwed into the metal stem.  Stem is hanging about 2.5" below the hole of the medallion, and the threaded nipple at the end of it is 0.5" in diameter.  I nipple is part of a 1.5" extension that can be unscrewed to leave a 3/4" diameter threaded stem that goes several inches up to the junction box.

The innermost medallion diameter is between 3" and 3.5" depending upon whether you measure the only the flat surface or from the inner diameter of the decorative carving.

I'd like to install a semi-flush mount fixture (possibly having a pancake canopy rather than the bell-shaped canopy a chandelier would have) to this without removing or cutting the medallion further (chandelier was too low for the room).

My first thought was to mount a 3" pancake junction box to the threaded stem with a 3/4" nut and large washer, then mount the fixture to that.  That seems like a hack, **is there a better way?**

UPDATE: In reference to what light I want to install, we are still making a final decision, but the idea was a light structured like this: https://www.wayfair.com/lighting/pdp/foundstone-vivian-3-light-126-cluster-cylinder-semi-flush-mount-w000825429.html or like this: https://www.wayfair.com/lighting/pdp/zipcode-design-lavina-3-light-15-shaded-tiered-semi-flush-mount-w003219538.html.  They have a pancake-shaped canopy with a very short rod leading to the light itself.

A fully flush mounted (surface mount?) fixture (such as: https://www.wayfair.com/lighting/pdp/orren-ellis-mcatee-2-light-shaded-drum-flush-mount-qz12691.html?piid=28665557%2C28665558) is not desirable as we would like to keep the medallion visible.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You could help us give you ideas by better describing (or posting a pic of) the fixture you intend to fasten to that medallion. "Semi-flush" just isn't enough to work with...

Comment: In lighting, "surface mount" means what it says; "flush" (or "recessed") means the entire fixture is recessed and the diffuser/lens is *flush* with the finished ceiling; "semi-flush" usually refers to fixtures where part of the fixture is recessed in the ceiling and the lens/diffuser hangs down a bit... so... what kind of fixture are you talking about?

Comment: Why not remove the threaded shaft (it should unscrew) and the escutcheon, which may be held in place by dried paint, since I assume there was a large nut or the fixture itself to retain it?

Comment: That's a fantastic medallion and I'm 100% in support of whatever light you choose to mount there so long as you save it!

Comment: Use caution with the “medallion” these are made of plaster in most cases , the pipe usually can be unscrewed and may be the original gas line that was for the original light. There are adapters From 1/2”npt to a standard hickey to hold a surface mount type shade in place.

Comment: @DrMoishe-pippik The shaft does unscrew (as did the 1.5" visible extension at the end that is visible in the picture), but I thought that might make mounting something more challenging.  I wouldn't want to mount a fixture or even a mounting plate or pancake box directly to the medallion - wouldn't trust it to hold.  Had thought since the shaft was already supporting a previous fixture of greater weight it might be better to find a way to reuse it.

Comment: @ed-bealI had not thought about it possibly having been a gas line before - will take a look in the attic to see if I get any clues on that.  And yes, I was concerned about the medallion being involved in any way in supporting the new fixture.

Comment: @jimmy-fix-it updated the original question with links to what I meant by "semi-flush".

Comment: Were the original wire connections up inside the medallion? Can we presume that there is a legitimate junction box up there? I ask because you may not need a pancake box, a fixture like in your second link might bolt up nicely to that medallion, all you would need to do is fasten a crossbar to the threaded rod, easy. I like the fixture in your first link better, but it has a very large ceiling plate that would not work with the medallion (without some alteration, anyway).

Comment: @jimmy-fix-it the original wire connections were inside the chandelier canopy (so the visible wires in the picture have not moved much since I took down the chandelier).  There is a junction box above the medallion to which the threaded shaft is attached (or at least through which it is run).  I wondered about the crossbar of an existing fixture - I figured I would have to get an adapter since those nipples are usually 3/8" or less, and that that might cause the ceiling plate to hang a small distance below the medallion.

Comment: Seems like the best solution here is a little bit of custom attachment of some sort or another (possibly even including a custom ceiling plate canopy since most the fixtures come with > 4").  Maybe not custom fabrication, but at least more unusual than would be found at a big box home store.  Any advice on where to find a broader array of options?

Answer (score 2):

The light fixture in the 2nd post should should be a perfect fit, You may have to extend or decrease the length of the nipple, Be careful just screwing it up to make it shorter, You could damage the wiring.